# Bash script that logs both terminal input and output

Tags: linux, bash

I'm learning bash and I think it would be good to have a log that contains all I do in a file (like `script` command do). But instead of using `script` I want to create my own bash script. So I wrote this:

```
rm file; tee -a file | bash 2>&1 | tee -a file
```

It works nice but I would like to log bash default prompt also. I found the `-i` option in `man bash` and changed my script
(I have to use `rm` and `tee -a` commands here instead of just `tee` because it creates a strange shifted output. So I chose the easy way):

```
rm file; tee -a file | bash -i 2>&1 | tee -a file
```

But it doesn't work! It executes and saves only one command. Is there any way to fix it (and understand the reason of it)?

Example of output for `cat file` after the first script:

```
echo 1      
1
echo 2
2
```

Desired output:

```
user@host:~$ echo 1      
1
user@host:~$ echo 2
2
```

Comment: You will never be able to get this to work. The `script` command works by creating a psuedo-tty (pty) so Bash thinks it is interacting with a normal terminal. What you are trying to do will always have unwanted artifacts such as echoing the commands twice. Note that Bash already maintains a command history. Many terminals also provide a way to save everything written to the terminal. You could also use the Tmux utility to capture what is written to the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I chose the easy way):
>
> ```
> rm file; tee -a file | bash -i 2>&1 | tee -a file
> ```
>
> But it doesn't work! It executes and saves only one command.

You do need to run `bash` in interactive mode to get prompts, and you need to ask for that explicitly (via `-i`) when its standard output is not connected to a terminal.

You're running into trouble because the child `bash` acts like it's in the foreground, on account of being in interactive mode, but it isn't actually connected to the controlling terminal -- the two `tee` commands are.  When the child `bash` executes a command, it puts that command into the foreground, but when the command terminates, the child `bash` fails to return at least one of the `tee`s to the foreground.

But that command isn't what you want anyway.  When running in interactive mode, `bash` echoes its input to its output, which is why you see what you type.  But that means that your command captures the input twice, once before it reaches `bash`, and again after `bash` echoes it.  You don't need that first `tee`, and removing it permits some other simplifications as well:

```
bash -i 2>&1 | tee file
```

And it turns out that that works for me fully as you seem to want.  It logs an arbitrary number of commands, with prompts and output.

Comment: Yes, that's what I need. (As I understood `bash -i` puts its prompt to stderr). Thank you.
Just want to add here: Using `tail -f file` in an other terminal allows to see user input in real time which is very convenient.

Comment: @dr.harm What do you mean by `Using tail -f file in an other terminal allows to see user input in real time which is very convenient` ? You see user input anyway already.

Comment: @Philippe Still useful I think